# ggplot2 geom_point with aes fill only displays black

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point, geom-segment

I'm having trouble displaying different fill colors with `geom_point`, only black shows up. I know I can use color to show different colors but it doesn't seem to work well with `geom_segment`. Here is an example what I'm getting, where the points are only showing up as black instead of the specified fill values in `scale_fill_manual`. Open to other ways of displaying the same plot and with different two legends, one for color and one for shape with different colors. Thank you!

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), mpg)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=factor(gear), xend=factor(gear), y = mpg, yend = mpg+1, color = factor(cyl)), size = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = factor(carb))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'green', 'blue')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('pink', 'light green', 'light blue', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange')) +
  coord_flip()
```

[The plot I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Wd5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `geom_point` and `geom_segment`, these would both need `scale_color_manual` to change the colors, which is of course not possible. However, if you use an open symbol (that could be filled), then you can map one factor to fill and the other to color. So, they can each have their own colors on the different scales. So, for `geom_point`, I specified the shape as `pch = 21`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(gear), mpg)) +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = factor(gear),
    xend = factor(gear),
    y = mpg,
    yend = mpg + 1,
    color = factor(cyl)
  ),
  size = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = factor(carb)), pch = 21) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'green', 'blue')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('pink', 'light green', 'light blue', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange')) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Whether you use `scale_color_manual` or `scale_fill_manual` depends on the `geom` type. According to ["Change Colors Manually"](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually#change-colors-manually):

> A custom color palettes can be specified using the functions:
>
> - scale_fill_manual() for box plot, bar plot, violin plot, etc
> - scale_color_manual() for lines and points

But the different plotting symbols allow you to get around those specifications.

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant!